# Why does git break if '/' is the root of the repository?

Tags: git, version-control, configuration, system

We'd like to use git to maintain system configurations.  Because sometimes configuration data exists outside of /etc, we've started doing something like this on our systems:

```
  # cd /
  # git init
  # git add etc
  # git add some/other/path
  # git commit -m 'initial import'
```

And so forth.  This works, up to a point.  As long as your cwd == '/', git behaves normally.  However, if you try, for example, to run git from inside a subdirectory:

```
cd /etc
git status
```

You get garbage.  In our case, thousands of lines of "deleted:" listings for files that clearly still exist.  This behavior appears to be exclusive to running git in /; doing the same thing anywhere else works just fine.

I can "fix" the behavior like this:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/ git status
```

And hey, everything works the way Linus intended...but this is a pain.  I don't want to set it in the environment unilaterally (because this would conflict with the use of git in other repositories), and I'd like to avoid a wrapper script.  Do I have any other options?

Comment: Note: Git 2.4.1+ will fix this (Q2 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30093777/6309).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `core.worktree` option on the repository takes care of this nicely:

```
git config core.worktree /
```

This works much better than setting GIT_WORK_TREE in the environment.  Yay!

Comment: Also, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete *guess* that you could use to investigate further, but I suspect that git's "find the `.git` directory" behavior is interacting with the fact that `/` is its own parent directory. Maybe the "stop at the root" logic has a fencepost-type error.

Comment: Ah, git.  Always a new surprise somewhere.  I like your guess though.  +1

Comment: This was also my guess (and why I suspect that setting GIT_WORK_TREE would fix it).  I'm just wondering if there's a more graceful way of working around the behavior...a git config option?  I see that there's a newer version of git out (we're running 1.63); perhaps I should see if that sill behaves the same way.

Comment: @NR: Hi there!  I like git better than the alternatives.  I think that they *all* have surprises (like Subversion's "Surprise!  You can't actually use svndump/svnload if you've moved things around!").

Comment: @larsks: sounds worthy of having a bug filed to me :)

Comment: Alas, upgrading to the current release of git does not resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in Git 2.4.1+ (Q2 2015).
See [commit 84ccad8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84ccad8dec1b8675699d70412def098d61456c55) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff), and merged in [7502b23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7502b230ced2de7398a292f3da79467065398044).

### `init`: don't set `core.worktree` when initializing `/.git`

> If you create a git repository in the root directory with "`git init /`", we erroneously write a `core.worktree` entry.
>   This isn't *wrong*, in the sense that it's OK to set `core.worktree` when we don't need to. But it is unnecessarily surprising if you later move the `.git` directory to another path (which usually moves the relative working tree, but is foiled if there is an explicit worktree set).
>
> **The problem is that we check whether core.worktree is necessary by seeing if we can make the git_dir by concatenating "/.git" onto the working tree**.
>   That would lead to "`//.git`" in this instance, but we actually have "`/.git`"
>   (without the doubled slash).

(That is why `core.worktree` is incorrectly set here, when `git init` is done at the root folder `/`)

> We can fix this by special-casing the root directory. I also split the logic out into its own function to make the conditional a bit more readable (and used skip_prefix, which I think makes it a little more obvious what is going on).
>
> No tests, as we would need to be able to write to "/" to do so.
>   I did manually confirm that:

```
sudo git init /
cd /
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
git config core.worktree
```

> still finds the top-level correctly (as "`/`"), and **does not set any core.worktree variable**.