# git how to point folder with all files in it, to the remote repository

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked)

My colleague has a zip archive of our remote git repository.

So instead of having to checkout all the files again how can we point his directory to the repository? We are using tortoise git.

Comment: You want to use your colleague's local folder as remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

Unpak his zip archive.  Now you have /the_app

Now `remote add` the remote repository.

Now you can make changes and `push` them to the remote.
Or make changes on the remote and `fetch` them in.