# Git "repository separate from work tree" solution not working under Windows

Tags: windows, git

See the answer that I linked to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603156/1445967

I could not get this to work at all under the latest Git for windows.  (Windows 7 x64)

I used git bash:

```
<my username> /d/<worktree>
$ git --git-dir=/c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git --work-tree=. init && echo "gitdir: /c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git" > .git
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/dev/gitrepo/repo.git/
```

Then I tried:

```
<my username> /d/<worktree>
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: /c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git
```

So I tried something slightly different, thanks to the way windows paths get stored...

```
<my username> /d/<worktree>
$ git --git-dir=/c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git --work-tree=/d/<worktree> init && echo "gitdir: /c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git" > .git
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/dev/gitrepo/repo.git/
```

This is copy-paste verbatim except I changed my username and a single directory name to `<worktree>` for SO.

Then I tried the following:

```
<my username> /d/<worktree>
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: /c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git
```

Then I looked inside /c/dev/gitrepo/repo.git/config and I saw this:

```
worktree = d:/<worktree>
```

Maybe this won't work with the windows path notation.  So I changed it:

```
worktree = /d/<worktree>
```

Still no luck.  Is what I am trying to do possible under git for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The only progress I have made on this question is the discovery that on the workstation I was using, the SUBST command was used to create drive D.  That is to say, C and D are really the same physical drive.

SUBST does not seem to completely break Git though.  I have the project on drive D and the git repo on a completely different directory on drive D and everything works.

```
username@host /d/ProjectName (branch)
$ cat .git
gitdir: d:\gitrepo\ProjectName.git
```

So the best answer I have is a workaround, where I advise:  In Windows there may be an issue:

```
1.  If the repo and working dir are on different drives
2.  If (1) is true and you use SUBST
```

But whichever of those is the case, the work around is one or both of the following:

```
1.  put everything on the same drive letter.  It works even if that drive is a 'subst' drive.
2.  Use the windows "d:\" notation in the .git file
```