# Is it possible to store .git folder in a separate location?

Tags: git, version-control

I have many projects and each project has many branches on Git. I want to keep .git folder organized in one directory. This way, I have only one location for every repository while the source files can be somewhere else.

I did a few searches on Google but no luck yet. Is it possible to do that? If so, how to do it?

Comment: Quick Search on Google

[Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?][1]


  [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked

Comment: I've found that link before asking the question but it's not practical since I have to add additional parameter. I am looking for a solution like setting a windows variable, that way I don't have to keep track by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following variables (`man git`):

- `GIT_DIR` (or `--git-dir` param) to set the path to the repository.
- `GIT_WORK_TREE` (or `--work-tree` param) to set the path to the working tree.

For example:

```
GIT_DIR=/path/to/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/files git status
```

Related: [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/505467/55075)