# What will happen if I delete the .git folder after my work is done with git? Will I have to start new repository when working again on that directory?

Tags: git

You know, these **.git**s don't look fine in a PC when you work.So I have decided to delete it. But I'm afraid if it deletes my files/folders cloned/pulled from github under this repository.

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the .git folder does not delete the other files in that folder which is part of the git repository.

However, the folder will no longer be under versioning control.

Comment: If you delete the `.git` folder, will it allow you to use another repo in that place?

Answer (score 3):

Since having a `.git` folder in tour sources is an issue when working on your files, you can clone your GitHub repo while setting the `.git` folder elsewhere (similar to "[Can I store the `.git` folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603156/6309)"):

```
cd C:\path\to\parent\folder
git --git-dir=C:\path\to\myrepo.git --work-tree=myrepo clone https://<myaccount@githuub.com/<myaccount>/myrepo.git 
echo "gitdir: C:/path/to/myrepo.git" > myrepo\.git
cd myrepo
# start adding, committing, pushing
```

Of course, replace `<myaccount>` and "`myrepo`" with your GitHub account and your GitHub repo name.

But the idea is:

- in your cloned repo path C:\path\to\parent\folder\myrepo, there will be a .git *file* which will include the path of the actual `.git` repo
- the .git repo folder will be located in *another* path *outside* of your local cloned repo: `C:\path\to\myrepo.git`