# Specify a git directory name with git-init

Tags: git, .htaccess, github, bitbucket

I am using git on a web hosting account on public_html.

How can I specify the directory name it creates when I use "git-init" (which would create .git folder)

I am using htaccess, switching off indexing and changing the folder permission to 770 to stop the git folder being viewed in a browser or cloned along with using gitignore to not include config file within my git project (perhaps I need to change permissions on this file too?)

Comment: Why does the folder name have anything to do with permissions?  Assuming there is a need to change the folder name, would there be anything wrong with renaming manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/505467/1615903 might be useful

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assume when git init is performed, a config file is created pointing to the git folder. So if you rename that folder afterwards it will break. Permissions are edited to add extra security so contents cannot be viewed