# Can you change .git folder location?

Tags: git

All git repos create .git folder inside working directory. Can you change this folder location?

Comment: No it's necessary to set the git repository.

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/q/505467/6309?

Comment: Moving the folder would change the scope of which folders are under Git's version control.  But you could move it to a new location and reinit from there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can tell Git to create the `.git` directory somewhere else when you create the repository:

```
git init --separate-git-dir=/path/to/dot-git-directory .
```

`git init` is used to create a new local repository but you can also run `git init` in an existing repository to re-initialize some of its properties. The location of the `.git` directory is one of them.

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) says:

> Running `git init` in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates (or to move the repository to another place if `--separate-git-dir` is given).

Git renames the `.git` directory using the name provided as argument to the `--separate-git-dir` option. In the working directory it places a file named `.git` instead of the `.git` directory. The `.git` file contains the location of the actual `.git` directory.

If you want to put the `.git` directory back in the working directory all you have to do is to remove the `.git` file and put the `.git` directory instead. `git init --separate-git-dir` apparently cannot be used for this.

---

If you don't want to have the `.git` directory or a `.git` file in your working directory at all, then there are two solutions but both are inconvenient:

1. pass the `--git-dir=/path/to/dot-git-directory` argument to **all** Git commands;
2. set the environment variable `GIT_DIR=/path/to/dot-git-directory`.

The first option requires a lot of typing and your Git commands become long and difficult to read.

The second option makes it difficult to work with multiple repositories. Every time you want to work in a different repository you have to remember to set the `$GIT_DIR` environment variable with the correct path; otherwise you will mess the things up.

Comment: Awesome! Can I hack git so the `.git` file be also in another folder? Like one folder deeper, an set the directory to say a upper folder. Off course then I would have to run commands in the `.git` folder, probably..

Comment: When I use `--separate-git-dir` I don't find any .git file created to replace the .git folder, so actually that does the job to have no .git in your working directory doesn't it ?

Comment: @lapin If you cannot find it this doesn't mean it is not created. Read the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt

Comment: This is what aliases are for. `alias git="/usr/bin/git --separate-git-dir <DIR>"` and if there are some instances where you don't want the option to be automatically added, `alias gitv="/usr/bin/git"` for vanilla version. I know that git has an alias subcommand, but I don't know that you could invoke it on its own self.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the trick for me to re-establish from a given .git dir.

Move the .git dir to your desired dir.  If you 'git status' in the new dir, you will see everything is in deleted state.  The trick is to 'git stash' all the deletion away, at the same time, everything will be automatically re-installed/moved out of the .git dir.  So, the new dir is a completely new git working repository.

Answer (score 2):

Following this answer in case you want to do this manually (i.e. not using `git init --separate-git-dir`). I'll assume that in the directory `D:\projectfolder` there are your files and a .git folder. You want to move that folder to `D:\gitfolder`

In `D:\projectfolder` create a **file** (not folder) named `.git` with this content:

```
gitdir: D:\gitfolder\.git
```

In folder `D:\gitfolder\.git` edit the config file with this line under `[core]`:

```
worktree = D:\projectfolder
```

You can also do this with this command `git config core.worktree D:\projectfolder`.