# Changing the .git file name when having the working directory in a separate folder

Tags: git

As explained here [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked)

you can use the command `git init --separate-git-dir` to move your `.git` folder elsewhere on the local drive.

A file called `.git` is created in your working directory to point to the `.git` folder.

So, the question: can I change the default name of that file, making it something like `.git.win` for example?

Comment: Could you give some context: why do you want or need that file to be called something different?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I suspect you are trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: The reason behind my question was that my repo is backed up by Dropbox. That’s why I need to keep the .git folder elsewhere on the local machine. Since my machines run Linux and Windows, I thought the path in the `.git` file should change depending on which OS is running. But it shouldn't: you can put relative paths there with compatible syntax. My `.git` file now looks like this:
`gitdir: ../../folder/gitfolder`. This works on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **No**.

Git is looking for the specific file named `.git` which points to the original repo path.

A similar thing happening when you use `git worktree`. The worktree will have a `.git` file which points to the original repo path + worktree.

You must have a `.git` in your git repository.

[image]

And the same mechanism is used in `git worktree`

[image]