# Egit: How to create a git repository that is in a separate folder from the project workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

In Eclipse Oxygen, I created a project called `testproj` at `c:\jwork2019\testproj\`. My workspace is at `c:\jwork2019\`. The project's folder has the content of

```
c:\jwork2019\testproj\.settings\
c:\jwork2019\testproj\src\
c:\jwork2019\testproj\.project
```

I would like to create a git repo for the project, located at a separate repo directory at `c:\jrepo2019\`. I successfully created the empty repo `c:\jrepo2019\testproj\.git\`. I want it to track all the project's files located at the workspace at `c:\jwork2019\testproj\*`.

I have successfully created the project and the empty repo via Eclipse and Egit.

The problem is when I tried to Configure Git Repository of the project by right-clicking on the project and then `Team -> Share Project...`, I could select the repository created, but it changes/moves the project's folder location from my workspace at `c:\jwork2019\testproj\` to `c:\jrepo2019\testproj\testproj\`.

[image]

I would like the project workspace directory stays in `c:\jwork2019` instead of moving the project directory to the repository folder `c:\jrepo2019\...`.

I am guessing that I can do that via git command line by just `git add c:\jworks2019\testproj\*`, but I don't think I have the git command line installed, I only have git on Eclipse.

I found the question [Can I store the .git folder outside the files I want tracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked) that has the same goal. But it does it on linux command line.

Is this achievable in eclipse? And how can I do what I wanna do? Thanks