# In Visual Studio 2019, can I set my local source control repository to somewhere other than in my solution folder?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019 Community, Win10 Pro 64

I'm new to VS 2017 and 2019 and not all that familiar with git, but I have been able to set up a git repository and commit my solution to all the way to the remote server, using VS.  If I understand this correctly, the files are first stored into a repository that exists on my local machine, and then I commit it to the repository on the git server.

While this all works just fine, I can't figure out how to place that local repository somewhere other than in my solution folder.  When I click on **File->Add to Source Control** in VS, it always adds it in a .git folder in my solution folder, and I can't figure out a way to put it somewhere else.

The reason I want to do this is that I do my development on an SSD for speed, but I want my local repository on an HDD so it doesn't consume space on the SSD.

Is there any way to set this up with Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 0):

You can do nothing from VS but you can do it by relying on the command line. Once it is set, you could you VS normally without problems.

There is a way to set the '.git' folder in another directory when you init or clone a repository. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548676/717372

But you could also easily achieve what you want using the 'git worktree' feature.

Do the steps :

- Verify that all the files are committed or stashed (you have a clean working directory)
- move all the folder on your hdd.
- From inside the new hdd directory, checkout a revision (the one you wish, but not a branch, to avoid a limitation due to use the 'worktree' feature) with `git checkout SHA1_OF_HEAD` or `git checkout $(git rev-parse HEAD)`
- Create and use a worktree on your ssd with `git worktree add c:\path\to\ssd master`
- Now you can work in the ssd folder from VS