# Need help setting up new multi project Git local repository with existing code

Tags: git, git-submodules

I was using Perforce and am switching computers and decided to try Git. I have several projects - source code, electrical engineering files, mechanical engineering files, etc. I would like to keep their commits separate. I also want to be able to tag different commits so that I can get back to a particular configuration (for lack of a better term).

In addition, I want the Git repository to be in a separate folder.

I do not expect to be sharing the code with an online repository or other people. So, I was going to create a local repository and add/commit to it. I'll probably just back this directory to OneDrive or have OneDrive point to the Git repository.

I've read many different blogs and questions but am at a loss on how to proceed and would be very grateful for guidance.

The directory structure is as follows:

`c:\Depot
c:\Depot\Source
c:\Depot\Source\Robot1
c:\Depot\Source\Robot2
c:\Depot\Source\Robot3
c:\Depot\Source\Library
c:\Depot\EE
c:\Depot\EE\Robot1
c:\Depot\EE\Robot2
c:\Depot\EE\Robot3
c:\Depot\ME
c:\Depot\ME\Robot1
c:\Depot\ME\Robot2 
c:\Depot\ME\Robot3`

Each of the "leaf" directories - ex. `Robotx` have further sub-directories that I want to track within `Robotx`.

What I'd like to do is have separate commit histories for each of the `Robotx` in the `Source`, `EE` and `ME` directories and also for `Library`. I don't want to use filters to separate them out.

Finally, I want the git repository to be at `c:\Depot\Git`

I went to `c:\Source` and did: `git init --separate-git-dir Git` and that created `c:\Source\Git` with what seemed like Git files and folders.

To add the first project, I went to `c:\Depot\Source` and did: `` git submodule add `pwd`/Robot1 `` and I got an error message: `'Source/Robot1' already exists and is not a valid git repo`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a Git repository in a separate folder, you need to set your [`GIT_DIR` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations) or specify `--git-dir` in your command line:

```
git --git-dir=C:\Depot\Git ...
```

And you can add submodules only if you have already Git repositories for each of your projects.

I would start simple first: simply `git init` in each of your project, and start adding new commits in your repositories.
Once you have added commits and pushed those projects to a remote location, then you can start testing submodules.

Comment: Thank you.  If I understand the second answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505467/can-i-store-the-git-folder-outside-the-files-i-want-tracked), with a current version of git, a .git file is created such that this option isn't required?

Comment: Yes, you can reference the path of the Git repository that way too.