# Splitting two parts of one working directory into two isolated git repos

Tags: git, github, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt blog with the following folder structure and want *assets/images* and *content* to belong in their own separate repo:

```
project
  - assets
     - css
     - *images*
  - *content*
  - components
  - middleware
  - layouts
  - pages
```

As required by nuxt-content, /content contains the site specific content, like markdown files that go in the about page and blog articles. I am placing article and page images inside /assets/images.

I currently exclude /assets/images and /content in .gitignore, but I don't know how to give them their own repo. There doesn't seem to be a clean way to have two .git files in parent directory 'project' and if I initialize a repo in /content it doesn't have access to /assets/images.

Comment: why do you want to keep it in a separate repo?

Comment: Try [submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository).

Comment: won't work with submodules, because they need to have a common root, which they won't. A cardinal rule in git is that the root folder is sacred. You want to have content as a separate repo? Fine. Want to have assets/images as a separate repo? Fine. Want to have content and assets/images in the same repo? Give them a common root -> that would be project. You'll end up cloning [two repositories in the same root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778796/two-different-git-repo-in-same-directory).

Answer (score 0):

You could put `content` and `images` in a subdirectory (say `blog`) and replace `/content` and `/assets/images` with symlinks to `/blog/content` and `/blog/images`.

Then manage the content of `blog` in a separate repo, and probably include it as a submodule in your nuxt repo.