# How to keep changes synchron between an open-source-package boilerplate and the project?

Tags: git, github

We want to open-source a package (*folder structure, Docker files, User models, Email handling*) as a base boilerplate to be used in different customer projects.

A clean separation is not possible. So how can we deal with **changing parts** for the open-source-package versus the individual customer project? How can we manage **both git remote repositories** in one project?

Comment: Can you maintain separate folders?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, some of the files need to be in the root directory. Also the idea is to have a boilerplate for a general project structure.

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436125/two-git-repositories-in-one-directory. I think that approach is the best. You use two branches in same repo and not two different repos