# git - Multiple projects in single repository with version control

Tags: eclipse, git

I would to move my workspace to a remote git (BitBucket) to have more control about modifications.

I have multiple projects. Should I create one repository for each project? Or can I create just one repository making commit for single projects?

I use Eclipse (egit).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two git repositories in one directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436125/two-git-repositories-in-one-directory)

Comment: You should definitely create separate repositories for each project. Note that you will still have local repositories as well as the remote repos in BitBucket.

Answer (score 3):

Better way is to create separate repository for separate project.