# How to setup git for multi project merge

Tags: git

I have two git-repositories:

- The main one from the customer
- A second one used by a subcontractor of the customer

The customer only provides one account to access the repository but the subcontractor has several developers also working on the same project. Therefore there is a second repository.

What I need to do is to merge both repositories periodically.

What's best practice to achieve this? Using an additional remote? Or a solution like this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313342/1623426) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain of your question. You have 2 repositories:

- `main` Accessible by `you` and the `customer`
- `subcontractor` Accessible by several developers and `you`

To keep track of the changes in both repositories, you should use additional remotes:

```
git remote add origin http://git.company.com/main.git
git remote add alt http://git.subcontractor.com/project.git
```

Then you can easily keep track of changes by using `git fetch --all`

In addition, you would be easily able to merge changes from the subcontractor into the `main` repository.