# I have made 2 git repositores in one directory. Now I want to get rid of one of them. How do I go about that?

Tags: git, github, repository, multiple-repositories

These are the commands I used to create 2 repositories in 1 folder.

```
git init .
mv .git .gitone
git init .
mv .git .gittwo
```

Now my folder structures looks like

```
.gitone
.gittwo
all_other_files
.gitignore
```

I want to delete the second repository such that my new folder structure looks something like this

```
.git
all_other_files
.gitignore
```

I am a bit confused on how to proceed with this. I have equivalent code and commits in both repositories. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why you created two repositories? Which problem was that approach trying to solve?

Comment: In the start of the project I thought lets have 2 repositories, one for organization I was working for and another for myself. But later realized it was a waste. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436125/two-git-repositories-in-one-directory) to make 2 repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From purely a shell perspective:

```
rm -Rf .gittwo
mv .gitone .git

# Check with:
git status
git log
```

But having two repositories in one folder is unusual.
Any git command would have to specify its `--git-dir` (`.gitone` or `.gittwo`)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Yes its unusual to have 2 repositories in 1 folder, I was kinda experimenting.

Comment: Experimentation is good, learning from experiments even better. Good luck on your git journey :)