# How to track and commit multiple repos

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I gave a project that's split in "server" and "client" repos. Most times I make a change involving both repos, but to commit and push them, I need to open multiple tabs on sourcetree, stage all, commit, message etc...

Is there a way of tracking all repos in a folder and push the relevant changes to the relevant repo with the same commit message?

I've tried submodules, and I do see them in sourcetree (pic attached)
[image]

but their commit/push must be made one by one...

Answer (score 0):

I am too new to stackOverflow so I can't leave comment but post answer instead. I think your question is relevant to this post: [Two git repositories in one directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436125/two-git-repositories-in-one-directory)

Comment: thanks, but I have multiple repos in different folders. I updated the question with an image about submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are two different repositories, there is no way to do a single commit for both of them.

I would suggest you to have a monorepo structure for your application.

Comment: thing is I would like to split repos for different developers (compartmentalize) so a monorepo will let all getting all access...

Comment: Then you would have to live with having different commits/pushes for both the repos.